# python import data from file, and get date sequence

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I have a txt file contain some lines, like this:

```
[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 35, 0, 4996), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 40, 0, 4998),datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 45, 0, 5000)]
```

how to load data and translate to list like this

```
[2013-01-04 09:35:00.004996,
 2013-01-04 09:40:00.004998,
 2013-01-04 09:45:00.005000]
```

---

```
for line in dataFile.readlines():
    print(type(line))
```

---

I get

```
<class 'str'>
```

how to do please

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. You should fix the source, to avoid storing the data as a Python list (`file.write(str(dates_list))` is *not* a good way to serialize a list of dates). Use `json`, `pickle` -- whatever is more appropriate in your case 2. In general, use `for line in dataFile: ..` instead of `for line in dataFile.readlines(): ..` -- could you tell me where did you get the `.readlines()` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will always have strings in a text file. but  you can convert the strings to datetime objects:

```
import time

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

dt = time.strptime('2013-01-04 09:35:00.004996', fmt)
print(dt)
```

or maybe i got you wrong and in your file you really have the string that looks like a list (please clarify); then you could  try

```
from ast import literal_eval
import datetime
import re

strg = '[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 35, 0, 4996), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 40, 0, 4998),datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 45, 0, 5000)]'

dates = []
match = re.findall('datetime.datetime\([0-9 ,]+\)', strg)
for date_str in match:
    args = literal_eval(date_str.replace('datetime.datetime', ''))
    dates.append(datetime.datetime(*args))

print(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text file is not dumped property for reading as json file.

its ok you can solve your problem as below

```
import datetime
output=[]
#I am assuming that you have already defined datafile
for line in dataFile.readlines():
    output.append(eval(line))
print output
```

but before writing data to your text file you need to use `json.dumps(object)`  then it is easy to get your object back by using `json.load()`.

Comment: I got this [[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 35, 0, 4996), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 40, 0, 4998), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 9, 45, 0, 5000)]] thinks

Comment: u got list of datetime objects   u can do like this     fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'   then 
 output[0][0].strftime(fmt)

Answer (score 0):

```
dateList = []
for line in dataFile.readlines():
    match = re.findall('datetime.datetime\([0-9 ,]+\)', line)
    for date_str in match:
        # I can get this
        print(eval(date_str))
        # Translate
        dates = date_str.replace('datetime.datetime', '')
        dateList.append(dates)
    # get this
    print(dateList)
```

Thanks ALL

Comment: if your input format is broken; you might as well use "dirty"  unsafe `eval()`: `import datetime; dates = eval(dataFile.read())` and then `print("\n".join(map(str, dates)))`